# 1062 Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY'

Tags: mysql

I simply cannot figure out what is wrong. I get  `[ 1062 ]: Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY'` when trying to insert data into the table `category_names`. I have checked that the column `ID` is `AUTO INCREMENT` and a `PRIMARY` key.

Shouldn't I be able to omit the column name `ID` from the insert statement and it would work?

It worked on another hosting platform but since I moved to siteground I got this weird error.

I know the column name accessbile is a reserved keyword, but changing it doesn't make a difference.

**Table structure:**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `category_names` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `category_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `locale_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `status` enum('1','0') NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `accessible` enum('1','0') NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `type` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `filter` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `offer_image` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'none',
  `uri` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `browser_title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `meta_description` text NOT NULL,
  `meta_keywords` text NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `description` text NOT NULL,
  `extra1` text NOT NULL,
  `extra2` text NOT NULL,
  `extra3` text NOT NULL,
  `extra4` text NOT NULL,
  `offer` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `offer_activate` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `offer_product` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `offer_product_qty` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `offer_percent` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=685;
```

**Error:**

```
Database_Exception [ 1062 ]: Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY' [ INSERT INTO `category_names` (`category_id`, `locale_id`, `status`, `accessible`, `type`, `filter`, `offer_image`, `uri`, `browser_title`, `meta_description`, `meta_keywords`, `title`, `description`, `extra1`, `extra2`, `extra3`, `extra4`, `offer`, `offer_activate`, `offer_product`, `offer_product_qty`, `offer_percent`) VALUES (724, 1, '1', '1', '0', '0', 'none', 'test2', '', '', '', 'test2', '', '', '', '', '', '1', 0, '', 0, 0) ]
```

**UPDATE:**

I deleted the triggers on that table. It seems to have fixed the problem. Will Test it some more.

Comment: i try your table and your insert code.. i don't have error

Comment: Me too..It is working fine @Cudos